# What's the easiest way to get a package from nuget.org into a private nuget server?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

We're looking at running a private NuGet server. I know products like ProGet have functions to get packages from NuGet and put them into a private feed. We're more interested in a bare bones approach if possible. I built and deployed a NuGet server using NuGet.Server and Visual Studio. I can put nupkg files into my packages folder and install from my private server into a Visual Studio project. I've had to manually download the NuGet packages and then copy the nupkg files. Is this the only way? It seems some NuGet packages aren't fully downloadable as stand-alone packages. I was able to get one by creating a dummy app, installing the package from nuget.org and then copying the nupkg file but that seems hokey.

Anyone running a private NuGet server that has a cleaner way to "copy" packages from nuget.org into their private server?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue in the past, i used this [Blog Post by Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/downloading-a-local-nuget-repository-with-powershell)

It contains a script that works "out of the box" (double checked it now on Win7)

Pay attention to the variables as the default script repository is Microsoft's and limit itself to 500 nuget packages.

Also, when downloading the packages ive noticed they are saved in ".Version.nupkg" and not containing the full package name (Happens in Nuget Offical Repository https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/)

EDIT:

Following your need to choose spesific nuget packages, ive added a few lines for filtering the packages

```
      param(
  [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,Position=0)]
  $PackageFilterBy
  )
# --- settings ---
$feedUrlBase = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669"
# the rest will be params when converting to funclet
$latest = $true
$overwrite = $false
$top = 500 #use $top = $null to grab all
$destinationDirectory = join-path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) "NuGetLocal"

# --- locals ---
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

# --- functions ---

# download entries on a page, recursively called for page continuations
function DownloadEntries {
 param ([string]$feedUrl) 
 $feed = [xml]$webClient.DownloadString($feedUrl)
 $entries =@()

$filter = $PackageFilterBy.Split(',')

 foreach($item in $filter ){
 $feed.feed.entry | %{if($_.id -match "$item"){$entries += $_}}
 }
 $progress = 0

 foreach ($entry in $entries) {
    $url = $entry.content.src
    $fileName = $entry.properties.id + "." + $entry.properties.version + ".nupkg"
    $saveFileName = join-path $destinationDirectory $fileName
    $pagepercent = ((++$progress)/$entries.Length*100)
    if ((-not $overwrite) -and (Test-Path -path $saveFileName)) 
    {
        write-progress -activity "$fileName already downloaded" `
                       -status "$pagepercent% of current page complete" `
                       -percentcomplete $pagepercent
        continue
    }
    write-progress -activity "Downloading $fileName" `
                   -status "$pagepercent% of current page complete" `
                   -percentcomplete $pagepercent

    [int]$trials = 0
    do {
        try {
            $trials +=1
            $webClient.DownloadFile($url, $saveFileName)
            break
        } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
            write-host "Problem downloading $url `tTrial $trials `
                       `n`tException: " $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
    while ($trials -lt 3)
  }

  $link = $feed.feed.link | where { $_.rel.startsWith("next") } | select href
  if ($link -ne $null) {
    # if using a paged url with a $skiptoken like 
    # http:// ... /Packages?$skiptoken='EnyimMemcached-log4net','2.7'
    # remember that you need to escape the $ in powershell with `
    return $link.href
  }
  return $null
}  

# the NuGet feed uses a fwlink which redirects
# using this to follow the redirect
function GetPackageUrl {
 param ([string]$feedUrlBase) 
 $resp = [xml]$webClient.DownloadString($feedUrlBase)
 return $resp.service.GetAttribute("xml:base")
}

# --- do the actual work ---

# if dest dir doesn't exist, create it
if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationDirectory)) { 
    New-Item $destinationDirectory -type directory 
}

# set up feed URL
$serviceBase = GetPackageUrl($feedUrlBase)
$feedUrl = $serviceBase + "Packages"
if($latest) {
    $feedUrl = $feedUrl + "?`$filter=IsLatestVersion eq true"
    if($top -ne $null) {
        $feedUrl = $feedUrl + "&`$orderby=DownloadCount desc&`$top=$top"
    }
}

while($feedUrl -ne $null) {
    $feedUrl = DownloadEntries $feedUrl
}
```

Using the script will be something like this: .\Script.ps1 jquery,Microsoft

Comment: Hmmm... I looked at this. I need the ability to select specific packages. Not being a powershell developer I'm not sure I have the chops to modify this so that I can pass a list of packages or the name of a package for it to download. I'll have to load the script up in the ISE and see if I can figure it out. Not sure yet if this is my answer, but the only response I've received so far. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this edit will help you get in line with your needs

Comment: I tried your code. Not enough room to post the error, but I got what appears to be an error for every package found in the feed... See "answer" post above for details on the error message. I'm not a PS developer so I have no idea what is going on with the code...

Comment: Put in some debugging:  write-host Entries: $entries.count = Entries: 51 using your parameters of jquery,Microsoft. Each entry I wrote out the input parameters to DownloadFile and got this: DownloadFile  to C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\NuGetLocal\..nupkg so $url and $saveFileName are empty. I'll keep poking. Maybe I can come up with something.

Comment: You're absolutly correct, i should be more carful suggesting untested code. edited

Comment: I appreciate the effort you made to help. Unfortunately I don't posses the PS skills to really figure out why this isn't working... Thanks anyway.